# Practical Imagemagick stack (combined) complex commands

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want a combined command that can perform the following task in single execution. I searched the internet, but hardly found any tutorial that guide us to write any stack command. I can found single command for each operation, such as `-composite`, `-blur`, etc, and I know I can pipe the command as such

```
convert ... mpr:- | convert ... mpr:- | ... | convert ... png:-
```

However, I want a combined command that use `\( ... \)` and `mpr:{label}` since this will increase the performance as all operations are executed in single process (pipeline in shell can degrade the performance, and the process sequence is required to be in order).

[image]

The process sequence as such:

1. put `flower.png` on top of the `frame.png` -> `mpr:framedFlower`
2. put `mpr:framedFlower` on top of the `background.png` -> `mpr:out2`
3. blur the `heart.png`, right-gradient-transparent the `smiley.png` and put both image on top of `mpr:out2` -> `mpr:out3`
4. annotate the `mpr:out3` with "Hello world" (placement=bottom) -> png:-

   I don't include the commands that I have tried because they are too messy and it will be an insult to those users who read it. I tried for many hours, but can't get it done. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't spent ages futzing with the exact coordinates as I am only using sample pictures, but this one-liner contains every technique you need to do what you are asking.

There is basically one line of code per element in the final image:

```
convert frame.png -resize 500x400\! \( flower.png -resize 400x300\! \) -gravity center -composite \
   background.png +swap -gravity northwest -geometry +100+150 -composite \
   \( heart.png -resize 200x200 -blur 0x8 \) -geometry +1200+250 -composite \
   -gravity south -pointsize 72 -fill red -annotate +0+60 'Hello world' \
   \( emoji.png -resize 250x250 -channel a -fx "u.a*(1-(i/w))" \) -gravity northwest -geometry +1200+500 -composite result.png
```

[image]

The first line reads in the picture frame and the flower and resizes them each independently because of the parentheses and then composites the flower into the frame.

The next line loads the background and then uses `+swap` to put it **behind** the framed picture from the previous line. It then sets `-gravity` to northwest as the origin for the ensuing `-geometry` before compositing the framed picture onto the background.

The next line loads the heart and resizes and blurs just the heart before compositing that onto the main picture at your specified position.

Next up is the annotation - the only interesting thing is that I set the `-geometry` to `south` which means that the offsets to `-annotate` are relative to the bottom centre of the background.

Finally, I load the emoji-thing and resize just it in parentheses before compositing over the main image. The only interesting thing is that I use `-fx` to alter the alpha channel (`-channel a`) and I multiply the existing transparency (`u.a`) by the fraction of the inverse of the distance we are across the image, namely `(1-(i/w))`.

Hope that is fairly clear!

**Start Images**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it works. Initially, I tried for `convert frame.png flower.png -composite -write mpr:a \ \( background.png mpr:a -composite -write mpr:b \) \ \( mpr:b heart.png -composite -write mpr:c \) .... png:-` and it keeps failing. From your answer, I just realized that we can `composite` image in the **image stack** rather than using `mpr:{label}`. Sorry for my late reply, I spend quite some time to re-read those tutorials. I will give a upvote when I get enough reputation, thanks.